# How to force drawnow Matlab GUI to draw in new window?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have used drawnow to draw the characters of the mnist dataset.. which outputs the following output

[image]

when i created GUI with matlab and calling drawnow to display images after loading it draws the figure on the open window giving the following output

[image]

my question is how to force it to draw in new window ?

Comment: @Rasoolll thank you for editing, much better now :)

Comment: ahmed, did my answer help you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me understand what drawnow actually do, in my case i stopped working on that project for around 3 days and when i returned to work again, that problem disappeared before applying your solution :)

Comment: Strange, but only for the better... :-) Maybe it has to do with the way you interact with your program. A figure is also made "current" by bringing it to the foreground e.g. by a mouse click. In that case it would help if you enforce the correct current figure always immediately before plotting something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`drawnow` only asks Matlab to flush the event queue and update figure windows; it doesn't determine how and where things are plotted. It's hard to tell since you don't include any code, but in your case it looks like you just plot the character images and the GUI elements into the same figure.

You can control which figure window a graphics operation refers to by setting the "current figure", whose handle is always contained in the variable `gcf` (graphics: current figure).

You generate a new figure and make it current by calling

```
figure
```

If you want to later make this figure current again, you need to save its handle:

```
fa = figure;
```

You then make a figure with a given handle current again by

```
figure(fa)
```

Some rough sketch of a possible program:

```
% generate figure windows
fa = figure;
fb = figure;

% plot something in figure a and make the screen update
figure(fa)
plot(...)
drawnow

% put a UI element into figure b and make the screen update
figure(fb)
uicontrol(...)
drawnow
```